# Automatically sync to a remote server

Tags: rsync, remote-server, automator

I was wondering if there is any way that I could automatically sync a local folder with a folder on a remote server. To preface, I'm pretty naive to this, and I've seen a few things online that might be useful but they're beyond my understanding.

Anywho, I was given access to a server and specific directories and can log in by going to **Finder->Go->Connect To Server** and inputting the following sent by our server admin **smb://research02a.mssm.com/shr1/genetics/psp**  and then inputting my username and password.

Is there a way that I can set up a directory on my local host that automatically syncs to the server directories (i.e. by using `rsync`and the Automator tool on mac). If so, any guidance for a newbie would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to implement continuous synchronization, you could signup for two Dropbox accounts. One for local and one for remote. You could then share a folder on local with remote using https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux.

Sharing a folder using Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/share-with-others